An odd two dimensional slice category
The following is preamble to motivate the question; for the main bit, please scroll to the bottom of the page.

Institutions naturally carry a two-dimensional categorical structure; in this post, we restrict attention to dimension $1$. For institutions $\mathbb{I},\mathbb{I}',$ an institution morphism $$\Phi:\mathbb{I}\to\mathbb{I}'$$ consists of

A functor $\Phi:\mathbb{S}ig\to\mathbb{S}ig'$,
A natural transformation



A natural transformation


such that the following compatibility condition holds:
$$\forall\Sigma\in{\bf Ob}_{\mathbb{S}ig}\forall M\in{\bf Ob}_{{\sf Mod}(\Sigma)}\forall e'\in{\sf Sen}'(\Phi(\Sigma))\Big(M\models_\Sigma\alpha_\Sigma(e')\iff\beta_\Sigma(M)\models'_{\Phi(\Sigma)}e'\Big).$$
We can formulate the above compatibility condition as a collection of diagrams

indexed over signatures $\Sigma$, where we read things in ${\bf Rel}$ and transpose the functions $\alpha_\Sigma$ to produce relations.
Dually, an institution comorphism consists of the same data as above except with the directions of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ reversed and the compatibility condition modified accordingly.
It seems like this construction is some sort of (co-)lax slice $2$-category of $\mathfrak{Cat}$ at a dagger category, but where the objects are parallel pairs of functors with natural transformations between them. Indeed, we can draw the $2$-D diagrams below


representing the  differing paths created by a morphism (or comorphism, respectively) of institutions, and observe that the above $1$-D diagrammatic representation of the compatibility condition is just pointwise coherence for the first $2$-cell diagram above, saying that the two face paths are equal. The second $2$-cell diagram unfolds one dimension to yield a universally quantified statement about a family of diagrams in ${\bf Rel}$ indexed over signatures, and unfolds two dimensions to a threefold universally quantified predicate, both in similar fashion to above.
These together suggest the following

Definition. Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a dagger category. We define a category $$\mathfrak{Cat}//\mathcal{D}$$ as follows:

The objects of $\mathfrak{Cat}//\mathcal{D}$ are parallel pairs of functors whose codomain is $\mathcal{D}$ together with a natural transformation between them, as shown below: 
The arrows $$(F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D},G:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D},\alpha)\longrightarrow(F':\mathcal{C}'\to\mathcal{D},G':\mathcal{C}'\to\mathcal{D},\alpha')$$ of $\mathfrak{Cat}//\mathcal{D}$ are functors $$\Phi:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}'$$ together with natural transformations as below  such that the following coherence axiom holds: $$\gamma^\dagger\circ\alpha=(\alpha'\star1_\Phi)\circ\zeta.$$ We define $\mathfrak{Cat}//_{co}\mathcal{D}$ in similar fashion, but with the directions of $\gamma$ and $\zeta$ reversed and the coherence axiom adjusted accordingly.


Here $\gamma^\dagger$ is the natural transformation obtained by daggering all components of $\gamma$.

Question. Does this definition (or one that subsumes it in a more general context) appear anywhere in the literature that the community here is aware of (maybe including the obvious second dimension)?

I purposefully avoided defining composition, although it'd be straightforward -- my goal here isn't really to define some new ad-hoc construction that happens to capture what's going on categorically, but rather to understand this phenomenon in a more general context. Any pointers are appreciated.
